# Christoffel symbols $\Gamma$ as an $\text{End}(E)$-valued one-form implies it is a tensor field?!

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

I'm currently reading John Baez's Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity for fun, and I stumbled across the following when talking about connections in a vector bundle. So, let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle, and $\nabla$ a connection on $E$. If we take a vector field $X$ on $M$ and a section $s$ of $E$, and express them locally over some open $U\subset M$ as $X=\sum X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $s=\sum s^je_j$ (for some local sections $e_j$ of $E$), then we get
\begin{align}
\nabla_Xs &= \left(X^i\frac{\partial s^k}{\partial x^i} + \Gamma^k_{ij}X^is^j\right)e_k
\end{align}
(in the book he uses the notation $A_{\mu j}^i$ instead of $\Gamma$'s and calls them the vector potential for reasons I haven't fully understood yet, but that's besides the point). Then, he goes on to talk about how to interpret $\Gamma$ more geometrically. He says the term $\Gamma^k_{ij}X^is^je_k$ is a local section of $E$, and is $C^{\infty}(U)$-linear in $X^i$ and $s^j$, which means it should be interpreted as an $\text{End}(E)$-valued 1-form over $U$, that is, a section of
\begin{align}
\text{End}(E|_U)\otimes T^*U.
\end{align}
Then, later on he says this is not just a local description, but in fact global, so $\Gamma$ is a section of $\text{End}(E)\otimes T^*M$.

Here's where I'm getting confused. If we take $E=TM$ to be the tangent bundle, then it means $\Gamma$ is a section of $\text{End}(TM)\otimes T^*M\cong TM\otimes T^*M\otimes T^*M$. But doesn't this say that $\Gamma$ is a $(1,2)$-tensor field over the base manifold $M$, which goes against everything that is emphasized in an introductory Riemannian geometry course?

I must obviously be misinterpreting what is written in the text, or have made a mistake unwinding the various "abstract" definitions. Any help in clarifying this is appreciated.

Comment: Don't think that's true, unless $E$ admits a flat connection.

Comment: @ArcticChar ok, later on he does mention something about being able to express any connection $\nabla$ as a sum of some $\nabla^0$ plus a "vector potential $A$" (which I interpret to be a $\Gamma$-like term). But I'm still very confused about the remarks made about $\Gamma$ being a globally well-define $\text{End}(E)$-valued $1$-form... something just isn't adding up.

Comment: If $E$ restricted to $U$, then a trivialization can be used to define a flat connection $\nabla_0$. The difference $\nabla-\nabla_0$ is a tensor given by the Christoffel symbols. This holds only on $U$ and not globally. Also, $\nabla_0$ depends on the trivialization. So it is not canonically defined.

Comment: @user580918: What Deane wrote above is described explicitly in pages 226-227. In particular, Baez writes that in order to have a global description one needs a reference connection $\nabla^0$ (written as $D^0$ in Baez's notation) and that, **when working in a specific trivialization**, one has a "standard" flat connection which can be used as a reference connection but it depends on the trivialization and so "it is not canonical" (quote from the book).

Comment: @DeaneThank you, I see now that I really misunderstood what was being said, and that there is no contradiction at all. If either of you or levap writes up your comment I'd be happy to accept it.